# Добавление данных в таблицу с использованием данных из связанной таблицы

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity

Добрый день.

Имеется база данных из двух таблиц. Структура таблиц строится через Entity Framework Code First. Структура следующая:

```
public class FederationMembers
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [Required MaxLength(10)]
    public string ISO_Code { get; set; }
    [Required MaxLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required MaxLength(3)]
    public string Number { get; set; }
}


public class LawEnforcement
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [Required MaxLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(300)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public FederationMembers SubjectOfFederation { get; set; }
}
```

Таблица FederationMembers предзаполняется на этапе инициализации БД.
Пытаюсь внести запись в таблицу LawEnforcement, и получаю ошибку, что система пытается добавить PrimeryKey в таблицу FederationMembers, который уже существует. В SQL профайлере стоит код

```
INSERT [tbl].[FederationMembers]([ID], [ISO_Code], [Title], [NUMBER])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)
```

Код добавления записи в таблицу LawEnforcement ниже

```
Context context = new Context();
Models.LawEnforcement lea = new Models.LawEnforcement();
lea.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
lea.Title = Request["lea_title"];
lea.Address = Request["address"];
lea.SubjectOfFederation = repo.FederationMembers.Where(c => c.ID.ToString() == Request["lea_fm"]).First();
context.LawEnforcement.Add(lea);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Почему система пытается добавить запись в FederationMembers, когда я пытаюсь добавить запись в LawEnforcement .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать следующее:

1. Добавить еще одно свойство в класс **LawEnforcement**:

   ```
   public Guid SubjectOfFederationID { get; set; }
   ```
2. Сделайте свойство **SubjectOfFederation** виртуальным:

   ```
   public virtual FederationMembers SubjectOfFederation { get; set; }
   ```
3. Добавить следующим способом:

   ```
   using(Context context = new Context())
   {
       var federationMember = context.FederationMembers.Where(c => c.ID.ToString() == Request["lea_fm"]).First();
       if (federationMember != null)
       {
           var lea = new Models.LawEnforcement()
           {
               ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
               Title = Request["lea_title"],
               Address = Request["address"],
               SubjectOfFederationID = federationMember.ID
           };
           context.LawEnforcement.Add(lea);
           context.SaveChanges();
       }
   }
   ```

После добавления и изменения свойств класса нужно применить изменения в базе данных.

Comment: Огромное спасибо действительно помогло. А не могли бы вы подсказать, как влияет "ленивая" загрузка на добавление элементов в таблицу?

Comment: @hamec, ленивая загрузка не влияет на добавление элементов в таблицу, а всего лишь является синтаксическим сахаром. Помогает подгрузить данные по требованию, пока контекст не освобожден через Dispose. Влияет на добавление поля с определенным типом. Для EF важно, чтобы было поле с типом и такое же поле с таким же именем, но с окончанием на ID. Про ленивую загрузку можно много найти информации, а что касается добавления данных, то просто почитайте про правила EF и все поймете.